# Python if statement with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to Python. I had just recently learned if statements and for loops. As practice, in the Python console, I was trying to come up a project/assignment and it isn't working as I'd like. Here is the code:

```
    PrimList = {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":2, "Wednesday":3, "Thursday":4, "Friday":5}

    appt_ = input("Choose an appt date. For Monday enter 1, for Tuesday enter 3. For Wednesday enter 4. For Thursday enter 5, For Friday enter 6")
Choose an appt date. For Monday enter 1, for Tuesday enter 3. For Wednesday enter 4. For Thursday enter 5, For Friday enter 6>? 1

    #as user input I entered 1, indicating Monday was the option.

    if (appt_ == 1):
        PrimList("Monday")
    elif (appt_ == 2):
        PrimList("Tuesday")
    elif (appt_ == 3):
        PrimList("Wednesday")
    elif (appt_ == 4):
        PrimList("Thursday")
    elif (appt_ == 5):
        PrimsList("Friday")
    else:
        print("That is not a valid entry.")
```

what I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'appts_' is not defined
```

I may be setting the wrong value to `appt`, using dictionaries wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: `appts_` is nowhere in your code.

Comment: whats the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# I have modified your code little bit.


    PrimList = {"Monday":1, "Tuesday":2, "Wednesday":3, "Thursday":4, "Friday":5}


# '\n' will add new lines

    print("Choose an appt date.\nFor Monday enter 1\nFor Tuesday enter 3\nFor Wednesday enter 4\nFor Thursday enter5\nFor Friday enter 6")

# input reads everything as string. so you need to convert it to int other wise 
# your if comparison wont work. >> you are comparing string to int << it wont work as You
# expected.


    appt_ = int( input('Your Choice:') )

    # dictionary items are accessed by [] bracket not ()

    if appt_ == 1:
        print( PrimList["Monday"])
    elif appt_ == 2:
        print(PrimList["Tuesday"])
    elif appt_ == 3:
        print(PrimList["Wednesday"] )
    elif appt_ == 4:
        print(PrimList["Thursday"] )
    elif appt_ == 5:
       print( PrimsList["Friday"] )
    else:
        rint("That is not a valid entry.")


**OUTPUT** 


    Choose an appt date.
    For Monday enter 1
    For Tuesday enter 3
    For Wednesday enter 4
    For Thursday enter5
    For Friday enter 6
    Your Choice: 1
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is what you are looking at, also you have to be sure to type cast your input as an integer so the user does not have to input a string (i.e `"1"`)

```
PrimList = {1: "Monday", 2: "Tuesday", 3: "Wednesday", 4: "Thursday", 5: "Friday"}
appt_ = int(input("Choose an appt date. For Monday enter 1, for Tuesday enter 3. For Wednesday enter 4. For Thursday enter 5, For Friday enter 6"))

#Choose an appt date. For Monday enter 1, for Tuesday enter 3.
#For Wednesday enter 4. For Thursday enter 5, For Friday enter 6>? 1
#as user input I entered 1, indicating Monday was the option.

if appt_ in PrimList:
    print(PrimList[appt_])
else:
    print("That is not a valid entry.")
```